# C# - deserialize JSON into ValueTuple

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, valuetuple

I'm trying to deserialize `[{"foo": "1", "bar": false}, {"foo": "2", "bar": false}]` into `List<(string, bool)>` type:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<(string foo, bool bar)>>(json)
```

But always get a list of default values - `(null, false)`.

How can I achieve correct deserializing?

P.S. I'm not interested in any model/class for that purpose. I need exactly value tuple instead.

Comment: Can you add you expected output json?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net maybe this can help

Answer (score 9):

In C#9 you can create a `record` and use the generated deconstructor to create a ValueTuple. I did see that you did not want to declare a model but it is the closest approach I have found:

Declare the record:

`private record FooBar(string foo, bool bar);`

Deserialize and deconstruct:

`(string foo, bool bar) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FooBar>(json);`

or

`var (foo, bar) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FooBar>(json);`

Answer (score 6):

The C# tuple feature was created to represent sets of values, not entities.

The names of the values are like the names of variables. Like variable names, tuple value names only exist in source code.

`(string foo, bool bar)` is, actually, just `ValueTuple<string, int>`. just like `(string bar, bool foo)`:

```
(string foo, bool bar) a = ('one', true);
(string bar, bool foo) b = a;
```

The tuple values are stored in fields named `Item1`, `Item2` and so on.

See for yourself how it works [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCsDetE+UgFCBAAyIBmA9hQDSIBGVANvQIYBOAlIgLL4fa4sMXCMQA3dogAuiALyJ8AW3YBjCgC5EAIgoA7AKZbaABwqMN0tgFd9HANwDR0gHTK2audqkB3ClofCTi6m5p5kLIwAzvoBQcgA7NKxuAC+sClAA=).

If you're that keen into using value tuples for that, you'll have to deserialize yourself:

```
var json = "[{\"foo\": \"1\", \"bar\": false}, {\"foo\": \"2\", \"bar\": false}]";

var jArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray> (json);

var list = new List<(string foo, bool bar)>();

foreach (var item in jArray)
{
    list.Add((item.Value<string>("foo"), item.Value<bool>("bar")));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve it would be to use a JsonConverter. For example,

```
public class ValueTupleConverter<U,V> : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(ValueTuple<U,V>) == objectType;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader,Type objectType,object existingValue,Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == Newtonsoft.Json.JsonToken.Null) return null;

        var jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(reader);
        var properties = jObject.Properties().ToList();
        return new ValueTuple<U, V>(jObject[properties[0].Name].ToObject<U>(), jObject[properties[1].Name].ToObject<V>());
    }

    public override void WriteJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter writer, object value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }

}
```

Now you can use the Converter as following.

```
var json = "[{'foo': '1', 'bar': false}, {'foo': '2', 'bar': false}]";
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<(string,bool)>>(json,new ValueTupleConverter<string,bool>());
foreach(var (foo,bar) in result)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"foo:{foo},bar:{bar}");
}
```

Sample Output

```
foo:1,bar:False
foo:2,bar:False
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest first convert the `JSON` to model and `Deserialize` the json

```
public class item
{
    public string foo { get; set; }
    public bool bar { get; set; }
}
```

Method 1 - using `foreach`

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filepath))
{
     string json = r.ReadToEnd();
     var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<item>>(json);

     Dictionary<string, bool> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
     foreach (var keyvalue in obj)
     {
          if (!keyValuePairs.ContainsKey(keyvalue.foo))
             keyValuePairs.Add(keyvalue.foo, keyvalue.bar);
     }
}
```

Method 2 - using `LINQ` without worrying about duplicates

```
Dictionary<string, bool> keyValuePairs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<item>>(json).ToDictionary(x => x.foo, x => x.bar);
```

Method 3 - using `LINQ` by considering duplicates

```
Dictionary<string, bool> keyValuePairs = JsonConvert
                .DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<item>>(json)
                .GroupBy(p=>p.foo, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.First().foo, x => x.First().bar);
```

Method 4 - using `DeserializeAnonymousType`

```
 var definition = new[] {new { foo = "", bar = false } };
 string json = @"[{'foo': '1', 'bar': false}, {'foo': '2', 'bar': true}]";
 var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, definition).Select(p=> (p.foo, p.bar)).ToList();
```

Comment: De-serializing to dictionary will cause exception if the Key parameter(foo) is repeated in the data.

Comment: @VishweshwarKapse, have changed the code to avoid exception

Comment: I do not wish create any dummy class for that reason. I asked about tuples

Comment: @anatol, check if Method 4 - `DeserializeAnonymousType` solves your problem